# QTextEdit as an HTML editor

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5, qtextedit

I'm trying to create an HTML, CSS, and JavaScript editor using Qt. The problem I keep running into is whenever I load an HTML file, the `QTextEdit` will display it, but without any of the HTML tags, which I need. I've tried to set the text using several functions (when loading the file) `toHtml()`, `setText()`, and `setDocument()`, but to no avail. Is there any way of doing this? Do I have to read the file line by line and insert it that way?

As an example of what's going on:

helloworld.html

```
    <html>
     hello world!
    </html>
```

when loading in to `QTextEdit`, it displays:

```
    hello world!
```

I would like `QTextEdit` to display:

```
    <html>
     hello world!
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not interested in the rich text capability of `QTextEdit` you should have a look at [`QPlainTextEdit`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qplaintextedit.html). `QPlainTextEdit` is optimized to handle large documents and to respond quickly to user input. It is based on the same technology and concepts as `QTextEdit`, but is optimized for plain text handling.

If you for some reason still would want to use `QTextEdit`, you can use the function `QTextEdit::setPlainText(const QString&)` to insert plain text.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Use `setPlainText` if you want to display your string as is.